# Is Javascript injection supposed to work even for web pages with no Javascript whatsoever?

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, javascript-injection

One of the methods in my applications is using the Javascript injection trick described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376471/how-do-i-get-the-web-page-contents-from-a-web-view/4892013#4892013) to capture the entire HTML of a web page *after* rendering:

```
// This call inject JavaScript into the page which just finished rendering.
browser.loadUrl(
  "javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML(
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");
```

It works -- even for very rich web pages -- but when it tries to handle in the same manner pages that do not have *any* Javascript in them, it generates the following error:

```
ERROR/Web Console(1335): Uncaught TypeError: 
  Cannot call method 'processHTML' of undefined at :1
```

In my search for possible root cause or explanation, I found quite a few postings describing an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method *** of undefined at :1` with two typical answers:

1. Use [webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930623/webview-causing-uncaught-typeerror-when-loading-www-google-com)
2. "Usually, when the error is of the form Cannot call method 'X' of
   undefined, it means that whatever object you are attempting [to call X from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776847/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method-request-of-undefined/5784609#5784609) does not exist."

Well, the cause of the problem in my case cannot be #1 (setDomStorageEnabled), because I already have that set correctly in my code!

So the only other possible explanation is that the object from which I am trying to call `processHTML()` does not exits. That object is named `HTMLOUT` and it is created in the activity's onCreate(), after creating a WebView object and initializing it with `setWebViewClient()`:

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavascriptInterface(this, webView), "HTMLOUT");
```

That leads me to suspect that the JavascriptInterface object instantiation fails for some reason.

This is where my understanding stops and my questions begin:

1. Does what I have been describing so far make sense?
2. If so, why would the JavascriptInterface object instantiation fail?
3. Is it possible that the reason for the failure is the non-existence
   of any Javascript in the original HTML?
4. What can be done to work around this problem?

Comment: Did you make sure to enable JavaScript? `webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`

Comment: @kabuko Of course. I thought that was obvious from saying that `"It works -- even for very rich web pages"`.

Comment: Did you solve the error? I'm having the same issue but i can't solve it.